# How to get a property depending on the Role of connected User?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a Product Entity, want to get all the informations of product if the user connected is SUBADMIN, but I don't want the description to be received if the user connected is a simple ADMIN, I am using this groups annotations, and I know about read and write properties, but I don't know how to get the result I want.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
        itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"="read"}
 *          },
 *          "put"={"access_control"="isgranted('ROLE_ADMIN') or isgranted('ROLE_SUBADMIN')"},
 *          "delete"={"access_control"="isgranted('ROLE_ADMIN') or isgranted('ROLE_SUBADMIN')"}
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"="read"}
 *          },,
 *          "post"={"access_control"="isgranted('ROLE_ADMIN') or isgranted('ROLE_SUBADMIN')"}
 *      },
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProduitRepository")
 */
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private $description;

    // getters and setters here
}
```

Do I have to use ContextBuilder to customize this ?

Comment: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically

Comment: Did you ask for closing it ?

Comment: No, I've just posted the link. Although with the link it probably doesn't need an answer, right?

Comment: Yes, It does not, I already entionned that in my question, if I have to use ContextBuilder, but I don't know for what reason people are asking to close my question, duplicate ? Don't think so, not clear ? I don't think so ? More focus ? what ? I don't know

Comment: thanks anyways, I managed to find a solution

Comment: @TaouBen you can see the close flags but not the reasons? Two votes as "Needs debugging details".